# Can't create a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I try to create a new controller in my asp.Net application, I get the following error:

> Error There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Could
>   not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\BJG0EWTW.TCG\HL8L41EG.WHG\d0b69070\008ca297_79e0ce01\Templates\PackageVersions.xml'.'

Since it seems to be an error to do with missing files, note that I haven't added any code snippets.

Do any of you have an idea of what's wrong?

Just so you know, I didn't start an MVC project, I was just trying to use an MVC feature.

Comment: Are you trying to add a Controller to an existing ASP.NET Webform project?

Comment: That was it, but now I created an MVC 5 project ad it worked fine.

Comment: Use the online templates to create the MVC control